# VSC Python extension - disable autocomplete on function call

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

After searching for 2 hours trying to fix this simple problem, I decided to post a question here.

For years I have been using Python extension inside the VSC, and now after clean install of my os and upgrading to the newest version of Python extension, code suggestions seems to have changed.

When I select the function from a suggestion menu, now it is autocompleted with names of the parameters that function receives (like a snippet). This frustrates me sometimes and I like more the way it was done before.

Before, only the method name was autocompleted and the arguments had to be written manually, but the method info dialog was opened indicating the names of method parameters.

Please, does anybody know how to disable the autocomplete feature?